# How to change the size of a sign

Tags: javascript, css

I want to change the sign ^ to be wider and bigger when written over a letter like this: ô

How do I go on about doing this?

Comment: could you please provide your html snippet for better understanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although onerous and not accessible by default, you could fake something like this using CSS.  But I would consider [jhylands answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68895352/how-to-change-the-size-of-a-sign#68895388) to be the correct/best one; I only include this for completeness.

```css
.special-letter {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.special-letter .char {
  line-height: 0.4em;
}

.char.caret {
  transform: scaleX(2);
}
```

```html
<div class="special-letter">
  <div class="char caret">^</div>
  <div class="char o">o</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't believe we submitted such similar answers 2 seconds apart! Upvoted.

Comment: yeah, I've just been thinking about doing this method not long ago. Easier than having to go through the other hazzle.

Answer (score 2):

To do this you would need to change to a font that will represent the character like that. You can include non-websafe font in a page https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_fonts.asp

The other option would be to use a javascript latex renderer and use that to specify that you want a wider hat.
[Javascript tex](https://latex.js.org/)
[Making a hat wider in latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/391188/how-to-adjust-the-length-of-the-hat)

Comment: Would love if there was a more practical way of doing it.

Comment: You could include an image, even if that is using latex http://www.math.union.edu/~dpvc/jsMath/ <- this might solve the issue

Comment: I'm basing that on this question, I know that you can use it for equations. I think that might be the best route other than using a different font.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/391188/how-to-adjust-the-length-of-the-hat

Comment: Thing is I want to change both the color and font size of a word the sign is being used in, so I would love if there was a responsive option of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Shipping a custom font with your new "o-with-wide-circumflex" character inside, as suggested in the other answer, is probably the best solution. However, depending on your requirements, it should be possible to approximate what you want with just CSS:

```css
.c {
  transform: scaleX(3);
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: -0.25em;
}
```

```html
<h1>Rhône</h1>

<h1>Rho<span class="c">&#770;</span>ne</h1>
```

This scales a combining circumflex character horizontally to make it wider, then nudges it to the left slightly.

Note:

1. Screen readers may have trouble with this trickery, and no longer be able to pronounce the word. Use the `aria-label` and `aria-hidden` attributes if accessibility is a factor.
2. Whether it looks reasonable/pretty will depend on the browser, font, rendering library and so on. It happens to kinda-sorta look okay here (Chrome, Linux).